# What steps are necessary to build secure database queries from user input?

Tags: database, security

Example Drupal 6 query:

```
$q = db_query("SELECT id FROM {table} WHERE no = %d AND name LIKE '%%%s%%'", 
               $_GET['something'], $_GET['something_else']);
```

Example Drupal 7 query:

```
$q = new EntityFieldQuery();
$q->entityCondition('entity_type', 'some_entity')
  ->propertyCondition('id', $_GET['something'])
  ->fieldCondition('field_name', 'value', '%'.$_GET['something_else'].'%', 'like');
```

The $_GET values could be anything the user can technically send. Should additional steps be taken like using PHP-s `is_numeric` function for numbers and `db_escape_string()` for strings to make sure the input wont cause any harm or are the queries already secure? Does the same count for other Database API functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "secure." If your goal is just to block sql injection then yes, that's it :) For Drupal 6, be sure you are using the right placeholder based on [db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6) docs:

> Valid %-modifiers are: %s, %d, %f, %b (binary data, do not enclose in
>   '') and %%.

And be sure that you enclose the %s placeholder in ''. Failure to match these properly can lead to sql injection.

Drupal 7 takes care of that for you. Even if you use the [Drupal 7 db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7) you use placeholders like :name and it will figure out the data type and take care of proper filtering/substitution/quoting for you.

The other security related topic for queries is the node access system. In Drupal 6 you should use [db_rewrite_sql](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6). In Drupal 7 be sure to use $query->addTag('node_access'); if you are querying for nodes.

This system of preventing SQL Injection as part of the API is, in my opinion, one of the great features of Drupal. Similar functions that perform both functional and security features are the t() and l() function which will prevent XSS when they are used properly.

Comment: Thanks! That covers what I wanted to know and confirms the bits of information I managed to obtain from other sources.